# Windows Server Service Bus. Incorrect request URI format

Tags: c#, azure

I am currently trying to install **Windows Server Service Bus 1.0** (on my PC, to allow on-premise development for Windows Azure) but whenever I try and access the Service Bus, either via Service Bus Explorer (1.8) or using the [test application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj542433%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) from the MSDN website I get the following exceptions.

I am sure these are the same issue.

This one is via the console application I have written:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Incorrect request Uri format..TrackingId:b22ffa03-4479-43c4-ab34-4d16324fb943_********,TimeStamp:16/07/2013 07:40:23
```

This one is via the Service Bus Explorer:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Incorrect request Uri format..TrackingId:242b22c8-d9e9-4e48-aca0-4faa7b71c349_**********,TimeStamp:16/07/2013 08:17:35. Method <GetQueues>b__26:
```

Can anyone please help? I think I have not configured the Service Bus correctly, but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

When configuring the Service Bus, I used the standard settings using the Service Bus configuration tool which appeared to work correctly. (i.e. in the log there were no errors and none were reported).

Should you need any further information please ask!

Thank you in advance

For the sake of completeness here is the full stack trace my console app produces...

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Incorrect request Uri format..TrackingId:b22ffa03-4479-43c4-ab34-4d16324fb943_********,TimeStamp:16/07/2013 07:40:23
  Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.EndGet[TEntityDescription](IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.OnEndQueueExists(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.EndQueueExists(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.QueueExists(String path)
       at ServiceBusConsoleApp.Sender.Main(String[] args) in c:\MyTfs\ServiceBusConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 37
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.GetAsyncResult`1.EndGetResponse(GetAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult ar)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this issue was resolved when I updated my local SQLServer 2008 R2 Database from SP1 to SP2.

I am not sure why this fixed this problem but it did!!

Some of my colleagues haven't had to do this to get Service Bus 1.0 for Windows Server working but if you're having similar troubles then I would suggest updating to SP2.